# Problema com o Tamanho do APK gerado pelo Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android, apk, visual-studio-2017

Estou Utilizando a versão do Visual Studio Community 2017 mais recente, e quando gero o apk, o mesmo esta ficando com o tamanho 90 mega.
Já fiz várias modificações e não obtive resultado. É um projeto simples com
poucas classes e funcionalidades, no máximo 10 páginas.

Já segui to tutorial do site oficial e mesmo assim não consegui resolver...

OBS: Em versões anteriores do Visual Studio, apenas mudando a configuração *Linking* para *SQK Assemblies Only* meu APK reduzia consideravelmente, e na versão mais nova ele fica com o mesmo tamanho alterando esta configuração.

Abaixo estão algumas imagens mostrando as configurações do meu projeto.

Desde já um muito obrigado...

[image: Archive]

Configuração do projeto.

[image: Configurações do Projeto Android]

Tamanho do arquivo

[image: Tamanho do Arquivo]

*References* do projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem imagens no seu app?

Comment: tenho sim...mas comecei um projeto do e coloquei o mesmo código com as imagens e consegui gerar o release... mas depois de inserir theme light ele parou de gerar release... já atualizei o visualstudio e continua o erro... vi muita gente com o mesmo problema na web...

Comment: Voltando ao problema do tamanho do apk, isso pode estar relacionado a quantidade de imagens do seu app. Tem muitas imagens? E o tamanho de cada imagem, em média?

Comment: Foi resolvido ....Não tinha muitas imagens, e elas não eram pesadas. O problema foi resolvido após algumas atualizações do Visual Studio... Obrigado a todos pelas respostas...